# How can I serve Multiple Domains (Java applications) with Tomcat Apache Server 9 (Like IIS)

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-10

I have a single Cloud Machine and multiple Java Applications that are usually serve by Tomcat 9.

**How can I serve multiple Java applications in a simple Cloud Machine?** (like I do with IIS and .Net)

Comment: [Virtual hosting](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html)?

Comment: @BasilBourque Write a comment with more information about it and I will made this message the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache tomcat 9, have Alias where you can alias your applications with different host names.